# TinyMce Shorcut: change background color of the selected text with keybaord shorcut

Tags: javascript, tinymce, keyboard-shortcuts, wysiwyg

I am using custom keyboard in my TinyMce editor like `editor.addShortcut('ctrl+45', 'format', 'Bold');` (or `indent`, `RemoveFormat`)
 But I couldn't find a way to create a keyboard shortcut to change background color of the selected text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
editor.addShortcut('ctrl+45', 'desc',['HiliteColor', false, '#FF99CC']);
```

Also you can create a TinyMce plugin:

1. go to your TinyMCE folder and open note.html
2. In the list of `plugins` add `background_color_plug`
3. open the folder plugins and create in it a folder `background_color_plug` and in this filder create a file `plugin.js` in which you should copy paste this:

   ```
   tinymce.PluginManager.add('background_color_plug', function (editor, url) {

   editor.addCommand('background_color_command', function () {
       var node = tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getNode();
       var color = tinymce.activeEditor.dom.getStyle(node, 'background-color', true);
       if (color =="rgb(255, 153, 204)") {
               newcolor = "transparent";
       }
       else{
               newcolor ="#FF99CC";
       }
           tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('HiliteColor', false, newcolor);
   });  

   editor.addShortcut('ctrl+45', 'background_color_desc', 'background_color_command');
   });
   ```